# Bootstrap 3.0 Affix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to fix a right hand col to the top of the window (when scrolling) using Bootstrap 3.0 and affix.

This is the html for the element:

`<div class="col-lg-4  right-hand-bar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="477">`

This is the css:

```
.right-hand-bar.affix {
    width: 390px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

In the example [here](http://nerdswithhair.com/themes/uno/blog.html) you will see that a few strange things are happening.

- The fixed .right-hand-bar (popular blog posts etc) jumps to the right of the screen (due to position fixed being applied).  I don't really want to mess about with the right positioning as the site is responsive.
- The fixed bar jumps outside of the main container.
- I've had to add a width to the fixed element which I'd rather not (due to it being responsive).
- I'd also like it to stop scrolling with the page when the bottom of the fixed element hits the top of the footer (or an offset value from the footer).

Can anyone help with any of these.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap a media query for `.right-hand-bar.affix` styles, so they only apply to the desktop version. You don't want it to be fixed on small-screens anyway.

Then add `position: relative;` to the styles for `.row`, and the `.right-hand-bar` will be affixed relative to that container instead of to the entire page.